# What is the meaning of 'see for '?

Tags: meaning

“**Independently**, I want to **see for** each tank, what are the levels not only of the tritium, which dominates by far the radioactivity, but all those minor elements, cesium, strontium, that are still there to some degree.”
What is the meaning of 'see for '?
Does 'independently' mean 'in my opinion'?
thanks in advance .

Comment: This is a strange sentence even for native speakers, and shows some rather poor usage examples. The fronted *independently* would not be used by a native speaker that way. Here, I think it is intended to mean 'I want to see a separate indication for each radioactive element in each tank.' But it is somewhat ambiguous. It could also be meaning separately from whatever was being discussed in the previous sentence, perhaps an indication of total radioactivity.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about an incorrect usage.

Comment: @PhilSweet — If you'd been reading the scientific literature as long as I have you wouldn't find it at all strange that a native speaker would produce something as clumsy as this. To give him some slight benefit of the doubt, he is using the standard device in English of adopting a word order that emphasized what is considered most important by placing at the begining or early in the sentence. Your rephrasing is, of course, better and satisfies the wish for emphasis. He would also do better to divide the sentence into two. That would solve the ambiguity problem. But close.

Answer (score 1):

*See* and *for* don't form a [compound](https://www.spellingcity.com/compound-words.html) in that context. The author states that they *want to see* something, and they want to see it *for each tank*.

As for *independently*, the meaning depends on the greater context.

> **independently** *adverb*
>   1 In a way that is free from outside control or influence.
>   3 In a way that is not connected with another; individually.
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/independently)

The wording of the quote suggests that author might have meant independence from whatever they were referencing in a prior paragraph (definition 1 above). For example:

- Earlier experiments have suggested (some) results. Independently, I want to see (the results of the current experiments).

However, the style used in the rest of your quote also admits the possibility that the author wanted to see individual results *for each tank* (definition 2 above). This interpretation is weaker, but rewording the quote slightly and adding appropriate context highlights the point:

- Earlier experiments only reported collated data that didn't identify individual tanks. Independently, for each tank, I want to see (the specified data).

Answer (score 1):

“Independently, I want to see, for each tank, what are the levels not only of the tritium..." The comma after "see" is missing in the original text.

And "independently" means what the [dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/independently) says it means: *separately from other things*.

Answer (score -1):

'See for' means 'check'. 'Independently' means the levels of the elements must be checked for each tank separately, not the numbers added together.

Comment: "See for" is not a common idiom.  When you do hear it it usually implies checking on someone's well-being.